# How to wrap flutter text widget inside a stepper?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

How could I wrap the text widget inside a stepper widget subtitle?, These are some attempts I made without success:

```
return Scaffold(
    body: Stepper(
    steps: [
      Step(
          title: Text("fake title"),
          subtitle: Text(
            "This text should be only one line, if flutter is showing an error and you are tired of trying to find a solution, start praying.",
            overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
            maxLines: 1,
            softWrap: true,
          ),
          content: Text("fake content")),
    ],
));
```

And with a expandable or flexible widget:

```
return Scaffold(
    body: Stepper(
  steps: [
    Step(
        title: Text("fake title"),
        subtitle: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: <Widget>[
            Expanded(
              child: Row(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Text(
                    "This text should be only one line, if flutter is showing an error and you are tired of trying to find a solution, start praying.",
                    overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                    maxLines: 1,
                    softWrap: true,
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
        content: Text("fake content")),
  ],
));
```

The only way I achieved was using a Container widget, but I had to specify a fixed width, so it was not responsive.

Answer (score 2):

I found that there is margin/padding like 84.0 (is not exactly), where you can use to set the width  like this code:

```
        @override
          Widget build(BuildContext context) {
            return Scaffold(body: LayoutBuilder(
              builder: (context, constraints) {
                return Stepper(
                  steps: [
                    Step(
                      title: Text("fake title"),
                      subtitle: SizedBox(
                        width: constraints.maxWidth - 84,
                        child: Text(
                          "This text should be only one line, if flutter is showing an error and you are tired of trying to find a solution, start praying.",
                          overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                          maxLines: 2,
                        ),
                      ),
                      content: Text("fake content"),
                    ),
                  ],
                );
              },
            ));
          }
```